# step through json results with a delay between each?

Tags: jquery, foreach, each

I'm loading a JSON file and doing a `$.each` on the results.  However, I want a delay between processing each item in the JSON data.  I have the following code, but it waits 1000 ms then outputs all the `item.time` values at once.

```
   $.getJSON("data/data.json", function() {
       }).done(function(d) {
       console.log("Got JSON");
       $d.each(function(i, item){
           setTimeout( function(){
               series.append(item.time, item.value);
               console.log(item.time)}, 1000)
       });
   });
```

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following - made a few changes to the some part of the structure.

Unfortunately, didnt get to test it due to not having any data set.

```
$.getJSON( "data/data.json", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
}).done(function(data) {
    $.each( data, function( i, item ) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            series.append(item.time, item.value);
            console.log(item.time)
        }, i * 1000);
    });
})
```

Added the index element to increase as each element is going through as the delay needs to grow so its chronological order.

**Example:**

Say if you have 10 data sets, now using the `$.each` function, you can loop through those and append the correct element to the DOM (easy...).

Now if you want to add a pause between each element so the first one loads, then after 1 second, the next one loads, you cant use the static **1000ms** delay. You need to increase the number as it goes down the data set. Otherwise, all it will do is wait **1000ms** and then show everything at the same time.

To space them out, and within the `$.each` function, you get the index as a callback that can be used. So simple implementation would be to just times (*) the timeout so it starts with **1000ms** and then the next one would be **2000ms** (but just a one second delay from the first element).

Comment: Works exactly as expected. I don't understand it, but thanks! :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson - Just added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your call to setTimeout:

```
       setTimeout( function(){
           series.append(item.time, item.value);
           console.log(item.time)}, i * 1000)
```

All the setTimeout are called at the same time (in the loop) and they all trigger execution to 1000 from now. To space them, just multiply the delay by index-> 1000 * i and you'll get the desired result.